# How to speed up mysql docker container for tests?

Tags: mysql, docker, testing, docker-compose, database-performance

I use docker/docker-compose to run services and tests. One of the services is mysql:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    expose:
      - "3306"
```

Is there any way I can optimize the container's speed specifically for tests (e.g. keep everything in memory, etc.) ?

Comment: Hi planetp, please specify what takes so long. inserting initial dump.sql? db queries?

Comment: @ckaserer well, all of it I guess, as by default `mysqld` uses the file system and is not optimized for just running tests.

Comment: What kind of tests?  The main fixes for slow queries is (1) better indexes, and (2) reformulate the queries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you could run your database in RAM if you have enough space to do so. That might speed things up a bit.

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    expose:
      - "3306"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/mysql
```

---

**Source**

- https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/tmpfs/#differences-between---tmpfs-and---mount-behavior
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#tmpfs
- https://www.stefanproell.at/2019/02/08/lightning-fast-integration-tests-with-docker-mysql-and-tmpfs/

Comment: Eh?  `/var/...` looks like a disk location??

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, that’s the location inside the container that should be written to (e.g. disk location). The `tmpfs` notation Alters the write behavior of that folder. Instead of writing to disk on the host a temporary storage writes in memory on the host system.

Comment: This seems to speed up the tests a bit (about 5-7% in my case, on macos). Is this going to be more performant than configuring MySQL itself to use an in-memory database?

Comment: Haven't tried that, but it would mean a deviation from your target setup. Not sure if the tradeoff is worth the downside of configuration deviation

Comment: WOW! Unit tests went from minutes to seconds on WSLv2. But I didn't see vmmem tking up any extra ram so not sure where tmpfs is actually going.
PS - rebooted the computer and my test database was still there.

Comment: Glad that using tmpfs improves the time your tests are running. My knowledge in regards to WSLv2 is a bit thin. A system restart might not restart your WSLv2 instance. Does your database survive a restart of your WSLv2 instance? e.g. via `sudo reboot now`

Comment: I've just tried this for MariaDB (running in Docker on the drone CI). Not only did it speed up DB start time by about 30%, but it actually speed up Acceptance Test execution time by 25%.